# automatically share the contents into the facebook after the data is stored in our database in laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel

How can we share on facebook immediately after inserting data in our database: the title, description, images and other fields. in php more specifically laravel5.5

Comment: Go read [ask] first of all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto-share content in fb anymore, unless you call the fb-content graph api.